# Problems with Minimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm attempting to Minimize the following function with Minimize:

```
V0[Lambda_,m2_,k_,phi_] := Lambda + (1/2) m2 phi^2 + (1/4) k phi^4
```

and used the following code:

```
Minimize[V0[Lambda,m2,k,phi], phi]
```

I received the following output, which makes no sense to me since this function is easily minimized:

```
{Piecewise[{{Lambda, (m2 == 0 && k > 0) || (m2 > 0 && k >= 0) || (m2 == 0 && k == 0 && Lambda > 0) ||

                                                             2
                                              4 k Lambda - m2
>        (m2 == 0 && k == 0 && Lambda < 0)}, {----------------, m2 < 0 && k > 0},
                                                    4 k

>      {-Infinity, (m2 == 0 && k < 0) || (m2 > 0 && k < 0) || (m2 < 0 && k <= 0)}}],

                                     2       4
>    {phi -> Piecewise[{{Root[2 m2 #1  + k #1  & , 1], m2 > 0 && k >= 0},

                 2
               m2           2       4
>        {Root[--- + 2 m2 #1  + k #1  & , 1], m2 < 0 && k > 0},
                k

>        {0, (m2 == 0 && k > 0) || (m2 == 0 && k == 0 && Lambda == 0) || (m2 == 0 && k == 0 && Lambda > 0) ||

>          (m2 == 0 && k == 0 && Lambda < 0)}}, Indeterminate]}}
```

That being said, this function is readily minimized using:

```
Solve[D[V0[Lambda,m2,k,phi],phi] == 0, phi]
```

, which yields the correct solutions. However, I want to use the Minimize function as the "Solve" method fails for more complicated functions that I'm working with. For example:

```
f[x_] := (x^2/4) (Log[x] - (3/2));
fv[x_] := (x^2/4) (Log[x] - (5/6));

V1[m2_,e_,phi_,k_,xi_,xitilde_,Q_] := Module[{},    
    Z = e^2 phi^2;
    G = m2 + k phi^2;
    H = m2 + 3 k phi^2;
    Zp = xitilde Z + 1/2 (G + Sqrt[G (G + 4 (xitilde - xi) Z)]);
    Zm = xitilde Z + 1/2 (G - Sqrt[G (G + 4 (xitilde - xi) Z)]);
    Zg = xitilde Z;

(1/(16 Pi^2)) (f[H] + 3 fv[Z] + f[Zp] + f[Zm] - f[Zg])
];
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can the parameters be any real numbers? Or are they restricted to certain domains (e.g., positive reals)?  I think that's why you're getting a complicated piecewise answer.

Comment: The parameters are not restricted to certain domains. They are left simply as user defined variables. As I mentioned in the post, I'm completely befuddled because the solutions are easily arrived at through the "Solve" method, but the Minimize function returns an incomprehensible mess for what should be a simple function.

Answer (score 1):

If we can't constrain any of the parameters to a domain like Reals, I'm not sure I would agree that this is easily minimized. What if `Lambda` is complex? All of a sudden your function is generating complex numbers. Is $4 + 3i < 3 + 4i$? If you want to compare these numbers, you'll have to tell Mathematica how you would like the comparison performed.

What if `m2 > 0` and `k < 0`? Then your function opens downward and the solution appears to be indeterminate, which the output of your `Solve` doesn't show.

Keep in mind that setting the derivative equal to zero only allows you to find local minima AND maxima. `Solve` is telling you that there are 3 local minima/maxima but not all 3 can actually be a minimum here.

Also `Minimize` operates on the assumption that all variables are real, so it won't find any complex values. If we constrain the values to be real, the result of `Minimize` is correct. Though complicated to interpret at first, the conditions contain important information.

Let's break down the first part:

$
\begin{cases}
 \text{Lambda} & (\text{m2}=0\land k>0)\lor (\text{m2}>0\land k\geq 0)\lor (\text{m2}=0\land k=0\land \text{Lambda}>0)\lor (\text{m2}=0\land k=0\land \text{Lambda}<0) \\
 \frac{4 k \text{Lambda}-\text{m2}^2}{4 k} & \text{m2}<0\land k>0 \\
 -\infty  & (\text{m2}=0\land k<0)\lor (\text{m2}>0\land k<0)\lor (\text{m2}<0\land k\leq 0)
\end{cases}
$

Mathematica is giving you a piecewise function that defines what the minimum values of your function will be. For example, if `m2 == 0` and `k > 0` then the minimum of your function is `Lambda`. A more important case is the last one, which I'll come back to.

$
phi \to 
\begin{cases}
 \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^4 k+2 \text{$\#$1}^2 \text{m2}\&,1\right] & \text{m2}>0\land k\geq 0 \\
 \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^4 k+2 \text{$\#$1}^2 \text{m2}+\frac{\text{m2}^2}{k}\&,1\right] & \text{m2}<0\land k>0 \\
 0 & (\text{m2}=0\land k>0)\lor (\text{m2}=0\land k=0\land \text{Lambda}=0)\lor (\text{m2}=0\land k=0\land \text{Lambda}>0)\lor (\text{m2}=0\land k=0\land \text{Lambda}<0) \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$

This part tells you that the minimum occurs when `phi` takes on one of the values in the piecewise function. `Root` objects are often a bit of a surprise to new Mathematica users, but there are a lot of good posts on that topic so I won't go into them here.

The last case applies when none of the previous conditions have been met. An example is when `k < 0` and `m2 > 0`. Let's say `k = -5`, `m2 = 5`, and `Lambda = 2`. In this case, we get a downward facing $x^4$ curve which goes to $-\infty$ as `phi` goes to either positive or negative $\infty$. This means that the minimum is $-\infty$, but the value of `phi` is `Indeterminate`.